# Flutter change Height of DraggableScrollableSheet dynamically

Tags: flutter, widget

I would like to change the height of DraggableScrollableSheet when a certain button is pressed. So far this is what i have

```
..other code up here...
  double _sheetSize=0.8;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
  return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.29,
        minChildSize: 0.05,
        maxChildSize: _sheetSize,
        builder: (BuildContext context, _myScrollController) {
        return Container(
          padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40,vertical: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8),
                    offset: Offset(3, 2),
                    blurRadius: 7)
              ]),
          child: PageView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _stepController,
            children: [
              NotificationListener<NextStep>(
                  child: SelectTimeWidget(myScrollController: _myScrollController),
                  onNotification: (notification) {
                    if(notification.moveToNextStep){
                      moveToNextStep();
                      setState(() {
                        _sheetSize=0.5;
                      });
                    }else{
                      moveToPreviousStep();
                    }
                    return null;
                  }
              ),
...some other code here...
```

In this widget, i have used a notification listener to fire up an event that i desired to change the height of the sheet

```
              NotificationListener<NextStep>(
                  child: SelectTimeWidget(myScrollController: _myScrollController),
                  onNotification: (notification) {
                    if(notification.moveToNextStep){
                      moveToNextStep();
                      setState(() {
                        _sheetSize=0.5;
                      });
                    }else{
                      moveToPreviousStep();
                    }
                    return null;
                  }
              ),
```

Sheet height

```
maxChildSize: _sheetSize,
```

What could i be doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

After Some real struggle I later discovered that its not possible to do this for the DraggableScrollableSheet Api at the time of this publishing but there is another way to achieve this using the package: [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel).

Answer (score 0):

Sliding Up Panel is a good widget, althought in my experience, there are some trouble with the lateral expantion of the widget in smaller devices or trying it with smaller with, and the github project has not recently updated their issues.